# Where is the Compatibility Area in iTunes Connect?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, compatibility

When I go to the App Store on an IOS device and select an app and scroll down, I see this Compatibility area, which says what devices are supported for this application. In iTunes Connect, where is that Compatibility place?

Comment: It is my first time uploading an app to the app store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list is created automatically, based on the following Project Settings in Xcode: The properties *Deployment Target* and *Devices* in the *General* tab, and the *Required device capabilities* in the *Info* tab.